# Deploying war to wildfly 19

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, wildfly, jta

I am trying to deploy a war file to Wildfly 19 but getting a communications failure error. I have been trying to figure this out for a few days without any success. Google search did not yield anything meaningful :-(. I tried some of the suggestions such as changing the address from localhost to 127.0.0.1, etc. but did not work. Below is the error I am getting.

I have wildfly 19 on Synology (Diskstation) with MariaDB 10. I have a DataSource configured called PMProdDS with the connection URL: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/pmprod?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Chicago`

Thank you for your help!!!

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="portfoliomanager"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/PMProdDS</jta-data-source>
        <!-- <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Below is the error I am getting...

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"portfoliomanager.war#portfoliomanager\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: portfoliomanager] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: portfoliomanager] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PMProdDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PMProdDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"}}
```

Comment: Have you started the MySQL server?

Comment: Yes, I have started the server

Comment: Is it intentional you are using port 3307 not the default 3306? Have you verified you can connect to mysql on 3307 using the  mysql cli ?

Comment: I am running MariaDB10 on Synology and the default port it uses is 3307

Comment: can you connect to the mariadb server with a JDBC client ?

Comment: I can connect to the mariadb server through the phpMyAdmin client. As I was digging more, I tried to connect to mariadb through SSH using mysql -U root -p, and it would not connect. Not sure what the problem is!